# Using update with subquery in EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I trying to execute the following update, using EclipseLink 2.5.2 (JAVA 7):

```
String jpql = "update VagaoPatio vp "
                + "set vp.dataSaida = (select vp2.dataSaida-1/24 from VagaoPatio vp2 where vp2.estacao.codigo = :estacao and vp2.codigoVagao = vp.codigoVagao and vp2.id in (:idsVagoes)) "
                + "where vp.estacao.codigo = :estacao and vp.codigoVagao in (:codsVagoes) and vp.id not in (:idsVagoes) and vp.dataSaida is null ";
Query q = entityManager.createQuery(jpql, VagaoPatio.class);
q.setParameter(...); // I set all parameters...
q.executeUpdate();
```

But I getting this error:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: EJB Exception: 
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.handleSystemException(BaseLocalObject.java:452)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.postInvoke1(BaseLocalObject.java:251)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.__WL_postInvokeTxRetry(BaseLocalObject.java:204)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:46)
    at com.rumo.pco.repository.VagaoPatioRepository_hiy2tu_NoIntfViewImpl.finalizarSaldosAnterioresEmAberto(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
    at com.rumo.pco.repository.VagaoPatioRepository$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.finalizarSaldosAnterioresEmAberto(VagaoPatioRepository$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
    at com.rumo.pco.service.VagaoPatioService.atualizaSaldoEstacao(VagaoPatioService.java:264)
    at com.rumo.pco.service.FotoService.criaFoto(FotoService.java:220)
    at com.rumo.pco.service.FotoService.oficializarFoto(FotoService.java:119)
    at com.rumo.pco.rest.FotoEndpoint.oficializarFoto(FotoEndpoint.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:402)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:349)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6089] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The expression has not been initialized correctly.  Only a single ExpressionBuilder should be used for a query. 
For parallel expressions, the query class must be provided to the ExpressionBuilder constructor, and the query's ExpressionBuilder must 
always be on the left side of the expression. 
Expression: [
Base com.rumo.pco.model.VagaoPatio]
Query: UpdateAllQuery(referenceClass=VagaoPatio jpql="update VagaoPatio vp set vp.dataSaida = (select vp2.dataEntrada-1/24 from VagaoPatio vp2 where vp2.estacao.codigo = :estacao and vp2.codigoVagao = vp.codigoVagao and vp2.id in (17031,17032,17033,17034,17035,17036,17037,17038,17039,17040,17041,17042,17043,17044,17045,17046,17047,17048,17049,17050,17051,17052,17053,17054,17055,17056,17057,17058,17059,17060,17061,17062,17063,17064,17065,17066,17067,17068,17069,17070,17071,17072,17073,17074,17075,17076,17077,17078,17079,17080,17081,17082,17083,17084,17085,17086,17087,17088,17089,17090,17091,17092,17093,17094,17095,17096,17097,17098,17099,17100,17101,17102,17103,17104,17105,17106,17107,17108,17109,17110,17111,17112,17113,17114,17115,17116,17117,17118,17119,17120,17121,17122,17123,17124,17125,17126,17127,17128,17129,17130,17131,17132,17133,17134,17135,17136,17137,17138,17139,17140)) where vp.estacao.codigo = :estacao and vp.codigoVagao in (6414371,6411061,3058247,7157649,6434789,6407978,6320155,6413374,6371485,6428916,3060012,6404707,6427600,6453911,6384358,6429785,6387772,3053253,3048284,6323600,6405789,6364527,6429505,6385630,6406131,6453023,7169345,6413773,6381782,6460984,3049507,6452612,6371159,6288405,6361609,3060152,6288821,6432867,6181678,6366252,6431593,6360394,3049981,6371761,6430058,3047946,6362303,6430023,6288286,6429246,6302165,7160691,6368409,6358837,3059383,6409865,6409407,6361722,6460071,6367411,6408117,977454,6289142,6452680,6409822,6460771,3051536,6288278,6368514,3055809,6457053,6382754,7168632,7165064,7156472,6316239,6457096,6427651,6254390,3047334,6254705,3047253,6430147,6460623,6427901,3049884,6363822,6369367,6431585,6365540,3565041,6288871,6369171,6368646,3057950,6361935,6364667,6364365,6409792,3047415,6428941,7167377,6323502,7164165,6410511,6420729,6413871,3061183,6379613,6404618) and vp.id not in (17031,17032,17033,17034,17035,17036,17037,17038,17039,17040,17041,17042,17043,17044,17045,17046,17047,17048,17049,17050,17051,17052,17053,17054,17055,17056,17057,17058,17059,17060,17061,17062,17063,17064,17065,17066,17067,17068,17069,17070,17071,17072,17073,17074,17075,17076,17077,17078,17079,17080,17081,17082,17083,17084,17085,17086,17087,17088,17089,17090,17091,17092,17093,17094,17095,17096,17097,17098,17099,17100,17101,17102,17103,17104,17105,17106,17107,17108,17109,17110,17111,17112,17113,17114,17115,17116,17117,17118,17119,17120,17121,17122,17123,17124,17125,17126,17127,17128,17129,17130,17131,17132,17133,17134,17135,17136,17137,17138,17139,17140) and vp.dataSaida is null ")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.noExpressionBuilderFound(QueryException.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.ExpressionBuilder.getDescriptor(ExpressionBuilder.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.DataExpression.getContainingDescriptor(DataExpression.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.DataExpression.getMapping(DataExpression.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.QueryKeyExpression.getMapping(QueryKeyExpression.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism$2.iterate(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2018)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.Expression.iterateOn(Expression.java:2680)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.DataExpression.iterateOn(DataExpression.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.iterateOn(CompoundExpression.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.iterateOn(CompoundExpression.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.iterateOn(CompoundExpression.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SubSelectExpression.iterateOn(SubSelectExpression.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ExpressionIterator.iterateOn(ExpressionIterator.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.prepareUpdateAll(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2061)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.UpdateAllQuery.prepare(UpdateAllQuery.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1603)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.invoke(BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.java:110)
    at weblogic.persistence.TransactionalEntityManagerProxyImpl.invoke(TransactionalEntityManagerProxyImpl.java:138)
    at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.invoke(BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.java:91)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy376.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.rumo.pco.repository.VagaoPatioRepository.finalizarSaldosAnterioresEmAberto(VagaoPatioRepository.java:350)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor255.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:109)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy381.finalizarSaldosAnterioresEmAberto(Unknown Source)
    at com.rumo.pco.repository.VagaoPatioRepository_hiy2tu_NoIntfViewImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:33)
    ... 64 more
```

My query works, I tryed on Oracle and it's just fine.

I removed the `-1/24` calculation too, to check if that was the problem, but I didn't change the error menssage.

I also tryed to execute as a native query:

```
    String jpql = "UPDATE TB_VAGAO_PATIO vp " +
                  "SET vp.DT_SAIDA = (SELECT vp2.DT_ENTRADA-1/24 FROM TB_VAGAO_PATIO vp2 WHERE vp2.CD_ESTACAO = :idEstacao AND vp2.CD_VAGAO_PATIO IN (:idsVagoes) AND vp2.CD_VAGAO = vp.CD_VAGAO) " +
                  "WHERE vp.CD_ESTACAO = :idEstacao AND vp.CD_VAGAO IN (:codsVagoes) AND vp.CD_VAGAO_PATIO NOT IN (:idsVagoes) AND vp.DT_SAIDA IS NULL ";

    jpql = jpql.replace(":idEstacao", idEstacao.toString());
    jpql = jpql.replace(":codsVagoes", codsVagoesPatiosNovos);
    jpql = jpql.replace(":idsVagoes", idsVagoesPatiosNovos);

    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(jpql, VagaoPatio.class);
    q.executeUpdate();
```

But then, the error is:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: EJB Exception: 
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.handleSystemException(BaseLocalObject.java:452)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.postInvoke1(BaseLocalObject.java:251)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.__WL_postInvokeTxRetry(BaseLocalObject.java:204)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:46)
    at com.rumo.pco.repository.VagaoPatioRepository_hiy2tu_NoIntfViewImpl.finalizarSaldosAnterioresEmAberto(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
    at com.rumo.pco.repository.VagaoPatioRepository$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.finalizarSaldosAnterioresEmAberto(VagaoPatioRepository$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
    at com.rumo.pco.service.VagaoPatioService.atualizaSaldoEstacao(VagaoPatioService.java:264)
    at com.rumo.pco.service.FotoService.criaFoto(FotoService.java:220)
    at com.rumo.pco.service.FotoService.oficializarFoto(FotoService.java:119)
    at com.rumo.pco.rest.FotoEndpoint.oficializarFoto(FotoEndpoint.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:402)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:349)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: incorrect_query_for_execute_update (There is no English translation for this message.)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:286)
    at com.rumo.pco.repository.VagaoPatioRepository.finalizarSaldosAnterioresEmAberto(VagaoPatioRepository.java:363)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor255.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:109)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy350.finalizarSaldosAnterioresEmAberto(Unknown Source)
    at com.rumo.pco.repository.VagaoPatioRepository_hiy2tu_NoIntfViewImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:33)
    ... 64 more
```

I'm too much time on this issue... No idea what is happening, the error menssages are not clear to me.

My other option is to iterate all my data to update each one individually, but I really don't wan't to do such a thing.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Just a guess. Try to reduce the size list of idsVagoes and codsVagoes. I suspect that the values passed to IN clause are exceeding the databse limit.

Comment: entityManager.createNativeQuery(jpql, VagaoPatio.class); where you pass in the class type is used for read queries.  Just use entityManager.createNativeQuery(jpql); since you are not returning an entity.

Comment: @Chris I tryed that, but I got the same error.

Comment: @HenriqueFernandesCipriano On database, using direct query, I got no problem. But I also tryed reducing my parameters on jpa and no problem again :(

Comment: I suspect of the version of my eclipseLink but couldn't have sure about it. I resolved by doing on object at the time. Very poor solution for my application tho.

Comment: You should have the eclipseLink source available to you - step through the setAsSQLModifyQuery method and see what happens; it should be creating a new ModifyQuery object from the DataReadQuery created underneath the createNativeQuery call. You might try a later EclipseLink version as I don't see why this would happen with the native query.